# How to group MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb

**Below data I have in my MongoDB collection.**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("758452161603f94848510101"), "exam_date" : ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z") "passed" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("758452161603f94848510102"), "exam_date" : ISODate("2020-01-22T00:00:00Z") "passed" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("758452161603f94848510103"), "exam_date" : ISODate("2020-01-28T00:00:00Z") "passed" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("758452161603f94848510204"), "exam_date" : ISODate("2020-02-01T00:00:00Z") "passed" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("758452161603f94848510205"), "exam_date" : ISODate("2020-02-02T00:00:00Z") "passed" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("758452161603f94848510206"), "exam_date" : ISODate("2020-02-03T00:00:00Z") "passed" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("758452161603f94848510207"), "exam_date" : ISODate("2020-02-04T00:00:00Z") "passed" : 1 }
```

**Below aggregation I am doing but I am expected different output.**

```
db.students.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: {$substr: ['$exam_date', 5, 2]}, 
        totalStudents: {$sum: 1}
    }}
]);
```

**actual output:**

```
    { "_id" : "01", "totalStudents" : 3 }
    { "_id" : "02", "totalStudents" : 4 }
```

**expected output:**

```
    { "_id" : "01", "totalStudents" : 3, "passed" : 1, "failed" : 2}
    { "_id" : "02", "totalStudents" : 4, "passed" : 3, "failed" : 1}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067634/mongodb-orders-sales-aggregation-group-per-month-sum-total-count-field/60067675#60067675 ?